# How to access SDCard storage in android

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want to access the storage of another app on Android 7.
Assume the following:
BundleId of app A: com.test.appA
BundleId of app B: com.test.appB

The external storage path is as follows.
/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.test.appA/files
/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.test.appB/files

I want to move the files in app A's files/ to app B's files/.
However, even if you request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, app A does not have permission to write to app B's external storage, and you will get angry.

While investigating, I found that file manager apps can access here.
With file manager apps, in addition to the permission dialog that appears when you request permission with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE immediately after startup, a dialog asking for permission to access the SD card appears when you access the SD card directory or attempt to operate it. It shows.
What permission is this requesting?
I investigated multiple file manager apps, but since they all have the same request wording, I suspect that the request was prepared by the system.

I would be happy if anyone could let me know if they have any information.
thank you.

Comment: Please dont talk about SDCard as clearly the paths ar not on a removable micro sd card. You are talking about app private directories on external storage.

Comment: But what you say does not come true. Every app on an Android 7/N device can read and write the app specific files on external storage of other apps.

Comment: `The external storage path is as follows. /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.test.appA/files` Sorry but i have never seen such a path. Nor i ever saw `/storage/sdcard`. Where did you get it from? There is though `/sdcard/...`.

Comment: You should use `getExternalFilesDir(null)` to determine app specific directory on external storage.

Comment: The 'getExternalFilesDir(null)' method only retrieves the path to your app's specific directory. What I want to do is access the specific directory of another app for data migration purposes. In my environment, I can obtain paths that start with "/storage".

Comment: You dont get it. The getExternalFilesDir() gives you app specific path that starts with /storage but not with /storage/sdcard. And further: to get the path for another app jucht change the package name in your app specific path.

Comment: I know that getExternalFilesDir() provides an app-specific path because I've verified it.
I also know that I can access it by changing the package name of the app-specific path obtained there and creating an instance of the File class based on it.
However, when you call File.canWrite() on that File instance, false is returned, indicating that you do not have write permission. (File.canRead() returns true)
I would like to know how to make File.canWrite() true and allow files to be moved.

Comment: The detailed discussion about paths is not the subject of this article, but the subject is that I want to move a file to the specific storage of another application, and I want to know what processing and permissions are necessary for that purpose.

Comment: You did not confirm that paths like /storage/sdcard do not exist. So it makes no sense to help you further.

Comment: The sdcard part is an example; it actually contains something like the sd card name (eg. 0123-4567).

Comment: Dont post wrong paths and dont call wrong paths example paths. Please rewrite your post and its subject taking into account all comments you got.

Answer (score 0):

> > Every app on an Android 7/N device can read and write the app specific files on external storage of other apps.

That holds.

But as a removable micro sd card is read only -except for the app specific directory on it- you cannot write files outside app's specific directory in the classic way.

But your app can if it uses Storage Access Framework.