# How to write to app storage specific for other apps

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want to access the storage of another app on Android 7. Assume the following: BundleId of app A: com.test.appA BundleId of app B: com.test.appB

The external storage path is as follows. /storage/0123-4567/Android/data/com.test.appA/files /storage/0123-4567/Android/data/com.test.appB/files
(0123-4567 is my sdcard name.)
This path was obtained using getExternalFilesDirs().

I want to move the files in app A's files/ to app B's files/. However, even if you request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, app A does not have permission to write to app B's external storage, and you will get angry.

While investigating, I found that File manager apps can access here. With file manager apps, in addition to the permission dialog that appears when you request permission with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE immediately after startup, a dialog asking for permission to access the SD card appears when you access the SD card directory or attempt to operate it. It shows. What permission is this requesting? I investigated multiple file manager apps, but since they all have the same request wording, I suspect that the request was prepared by the system.

my sample code.

```
File appAExternalStorage = getDownloadDirPath();
String appAExternalStoragePath = appAExternalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
appAExternalStorage.canWrite(); <-- This result is true.

String appBExternalStoragePath = appAEternalStoragePath.replace("com.test.appA", "com.test.appB");
File appBExternalStorage = new File(appBExternalStoragePath);

appBExternalStorage.canWrite(); <-- This result is false.
```

I want the result of appBExternalStorage.canWrite() to be true.

I would be happy if anyone could let me know if they have any information. thank you.

Comment: `How to write to app storage specific for other apps` Please change that to How to write to app storage specific for other apps on removable micro sd card. Or yet better: How to write on a removable micro sd card. As that is just the problem.

Comment: `File appAExternalStorage = getDownloadDirPath();` ??? Post code that every body can read. Your download path tells us nothing.

Comment: And further you know already the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77087381/how-to-access-sdcard-storage-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access SDCard storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77087381/how-to-access-sdcard-storage-in-android)